# "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FieldsProp'.ts(2322)" Not readable error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

""Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FieldsProp'.ts(2322)" Not readable error" I got this typeerror

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Card } from "primereact/card";
import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";
import { Button } from "primereact/button";
import { Password } from "primereact/password";
import { useSignInMutation } from "@/core/api";
import { InputTypes } from "@/components/FormInputs/types";
import Fields from "@/components/FormInputs/Fields";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

type LoginFormData = {
  username: string;
  password: string;
};

const SignIn = () => {
  const [signIn] = useSignInMutation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [loginFormData, setLoginFormData] = useState<LoginFormData>({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const signInClick = () => {
    signIn(loginFormData)
      .unwrap()
      .then(() => {
        navigate("/dashboard");
      });
  };

  const LoginCardElement = () => {
    return <Button label="Sign in" onClick={() => signInClick()} />;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="h-screen">
        <Fields
          type={InputTypes.Text}
          name="ietm_name"
          label="ss"
          placeholder="ss"
          id="ietm_name"
        />
        <Fields />
        <div className="h-full flex align-items-center">
          <div className="w-20rem mx-auto">
            <Card
              title="Login"
              className="w-full"
              footer={() => LoginCardElement()}
            >
              <div className="flex flex-column gap-4">
                <div className="p-inputgroup flex-1">
                  <span className="p-inputgroup-addon">
                    <i className="pi pi-user" />
                  </span>
                  <InputText
                    placeholder="Username"
                    onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                      setLoginFormData((prevData: LoginFormData) => ({
                        ...prevData,
                        username: e.target.value,
                      }))
                    }
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="p-inputgroup flex-1">
                  <span className="p-inputgroup-addon">
                    <i className="pi pi-lock" />
                  </span>
                  <Password
                    className="w-full"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                      setLoginFormData((prevData: LoginFormData) => ({
                        ...prevData,
                        password: e.target.value,
                      }))
                    }
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </Card>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignIn;

import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";
import { Dropdown } from "primereact/dropdown";
import { Calendar } from "primereact/calendar";
import { InputNumber } from "primereact/inputnumber";
import { MultiSelect } from "primereact/multiselect";
import { FieldsProp, InputTypes } from "./types";

const Fields = (props: FieldsProp) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={props.name}>{props.label}</label>
      {props.type === InputTypes.Text && <InputText {...props} />}

      {props.type === InputTypes.DropDown && <Dropdown {...props} />}

      {props.type === InputTypes.Calendar && <Calendar {...props} />}

      {props.type === InputTypes.Number && <InputNumber {...props} />}

      {props.type === InputTypes.MultiSelect && <MultiSelect {...props} />}
    </>
  );
};

export default Fields;

import { CalendarBaseProps } from "primereact/calendar";
import { DropdownProps } from "primereact/dropdown";
import { InputNumberProps } from "primereact/inputnumber";
import { InputTextProps } from "primereact/inputtext";
import { MultiSelectProps } from "primereact/multiselect";

export enum InputTypes {
  Text = "Text",
  DropDown = "DropDown",
  Calendar = "Calendar",
  Number = "Number",
  MultiSelect = "MultiSelect",
}

export interface FieldBase {
  type: InputTypes;
  label?: string;
  disable?: boolean;
  required?: boolean;
  show?: boolean;
}

interface NamedField {
  name: string;
}

interface FieldText extends FieldBase, InputTextProps, NamedField {
  type: InputTypes.Text;
  name: string;
}

interface FieldNumber extends FieldBase, InputNumberProps, NamedField {
  type: InputTypes.Number;
  name: string;
}

interface FieldDropDown extends FieldBase, DropdownProps, NamedField {
  type: InputTypes.DropDown;
  name: string;
}

interface FieldCalendar extends FieldBase, CalendarBaseProps, NamedField {
  type: InputTypes.Calendar;
  name: string;
}

interface FieldMultiSelect extends FieldBase, MultiSelectProps, NamedField {
  type: InputTypes.MultiSelect;
  name: string;
}

export type FieldsProp =
  | FieldText
  | FieldDropDown
  | FieldCalendar
  | FieldNumber
  | FieldMultiSelect;
```

[Screenshot 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBCmk.png)

In here when not passed the required props to  that type error not clear to developer I need to get proper error message something like I need to get required fields missing type error. g

Comment: Yes do you have the proper idea how this work?

Comment: I can explain more if you want?

Comment: This is expected..? You've not passed any props to your `Fields` component that requires props..? This is the error message you get and you can't change that. Do you get a different message if you only pass one required prop?

Comment: @PAB I know that thing. It did not mentioned which props are missing. That's the case

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce this in recent versions of React, but based on similar questions I figured that your `Fields` defintion might look similar to:

```js
import { FC } from "react"

interface FieldsProp {
  ...
}

export const Fields: FC = (props: FieldsProp) => { ... }
```

The problem here is that `FC` removes the props type since the default type is `FC<{}>` (no props). You don't have to use `FC` and instead you can type your props directly:

```
-- export const Fields: FC = (props: FieldsProp) => { ... }
++ export const Fields = (props: FieldsProp) => { ... }
```

This should give you an error that's "easier" to understand when you don't pass in any props.